# WPF UserControl Animation wont work..?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm really new to WPF so if you can point me to a tutoiral as well i will be very happy :)

here is my curreny code:

```
<Grid Name="Grid">
    <local:Card Loaded="Card_Loaded"
                x:Name="MyCard">
        <local:Card.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:Card.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyCard"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         From="1.0"
                                         To="0.0"
                                         Duration="0:0:5"
                                         AutoReverse="True"
                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </local:Card.Triggers>
    </local:Card>
</Grid>
```

**local:Card is a UserControl**

Here is why i use **x:Name=""** and not **Name=""**:

```
Because 'MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode' is implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute rather than the MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionPropertyNode attribute.
```

And i can see the Card and everything but the Animation doesn't work =\

Here is the card XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type s:String}"
             x:Key="src">
        <s:String>Foo</s:String>
    </x:Array>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="frontTemplate">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Image Source="Images\Card.jpg" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="backTemplate">
        <GroupBox Header="Back"
                  Background="White">
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton Content="This"
                             IsChecked="True" />
                <RadioButton Content="Is" />
                <RadioButton Content="The" />
                <RadioButton Content="Back" />
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl Width="180"
                  Height="250"
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource src}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource flipItemTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: (modified the tags) Silverlight animation is different from WPF animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
<Grid Name="Grid">
    <local:Card x:Name="MyCard" MouseEnter="MyCard_MouseEnter" />
</Grid>
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="sbdCardAnim">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyCard" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:5"
            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

C#:

```
    private void MyCard_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sbdCardAnim = (Storyboard)FindResource("sbdCardAnim");
        sbdCardAnim.Begin(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied your XAML exactly and ran it in a window.  The only change I made was to replace the local:Card object with a TextBlock (since I didn't have a Card usercontrol).  The animation ran perfectly.

So either your `local:Card` object has something strange that isn't allowing the animation to work or the  `Loaded="Card_Loaded"` method in this line:

```
<local:Card Loaded="Card_Loaded" x:Name="MyCard">
```

is interfering with the event trigger:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:Card.Loaded">
```

Comment: I removed the Loaded="Card_Loaded" and still nothing.
And i added my local:Card XAML :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the storyboard in either the EventTrigger.EnterActions or EventTrigger.Actions tags.

I recently dived in to some WPF animations....here's the link that got me started:
http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx

Comment: Cant compile with EventTrigger.EnterAction or EventTrigger.Actions tags.